# Aggregate return null values if queryset is none even if using Coalesce with default value

Tags: django, django-models, django-queryset, aggregate-functions, django-aggregation

currently, I am trying to aggregate on queryset. it's working perfectly but the problem is if my queryset is none Coalesce function is not working so default value is set null rather than 0 .

```
aggregated_data = queryset.aggregate(
                total_trips=Coalesce(Sum("total_trips"), 0, output_field=IntegerField()),
                total_orders=Coalesce(Sum("total_orders"), 0, output_field=IntegerField()),
                total_expense=Coalesce(Sum("total_expense"), 0, output_field=IntegerField()),
                total_payment=Coalesce(Sum("total_payment"), 0, output_field=IntegerField()),
                total_collected_payment=Coalesce(Sum("total_collected_payment"), 0, output_field=IntegerField()),
                total_driver=Coalesce(Sum("total_drivers"), 0, output_field=IntegerField()),
                total_utilized_driver=Coalesce(Sum("total_utilized_drivers"), 0, output_field=IntegerField()),
                total_vehicles=Coalesce(Sum("total_vehicles"), 0, output_field=IntegerField()),
                total_utilized_vehicles=Coalesce(Sum("total_utilized_vehicles"), 0, output_field=IntegerField()),
            )
```

current output if queryset is none :

```
{
  "total_trips": null,
  "total_orders": null,
  "total_expense": null,
  "total_payment": null,
  "total_collected_payment": null,
  "total_driver": null,
  "total_utilized_driver": null,
  "total_vehicles": null,
  "total_utilized_vehicles": null
}
```

expected output :

```
{
  "total_trips": 0,
  "total_orders": 0,
  "total_expense": 0,
  "total_payment": 0,
  "total_collected_payment": 0,
  "total_driver": 0,
  "total_utilized_driver": 0,
  "total_vehicles": 0,
  "total_utilized_vehicles": 0
}
```

Comment: Which Django version you are using? Did you try Value(0) instead of 0 as a parameter of Coalesce? Here is the [documentation for version 3.2](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/3.2/ref/models/database-functions/#coalesce)

Comment: currently, I am working on version 3.2.3. this issue is already fixed in version 3.2.16. Value(0) is also not working.  @DenizKaplan